# What Is The Quickest Way To Move Stuff Into Another Chest In Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A Different way then shift+click/A Way To fill up your storage without having to keep on shift clicking

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Arqade! Please describe what exactly is it you are trying to do (why isn't shift-clicking fast enough? are you trying to move lots of chests?) and what you have tried.

Comment: Are you doing this in survival or creative. If you are doing it in creative, fill in a chest and ctrl+choose ( usually the scroll button) it, then whenever you place it down, it will have the same contents every time.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of the same item, you can hold one stack with your cursor and shift-double-click on another stack to move all of the items from one container to another:

[image: Shift-double-clicking]

Otherwise, without macros or mods, shift-clicking is the best inventory shortcut to move things.